# wp7:how to pass data in use controll?

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-controls

I want to pass data from my form to user control in wp7 application.
But it user control give error system.windows.control.childview does not contain defination of "OnNavigateTo".

form1 code is

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("LoginChildWindow.xaml?param1={0}", path), UriKind.Relative));
```

userconrol code:

```
public partial class SongChildview : ChildWindow
    {
        public SongChildview()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);   
           string newparameter1 = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["param1"];
        }
}
```

Please help he how get data from my form in user control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your SongChildview calls does not contain OnNavagate method because it inherited in CHildview and navigate method only apply in page.

And if you want to send path to user conterol so second way is set globle your path and than access it.

Try this link

[Different Ways of Passing Values Between Windows Phone 7 Pages](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/different-ways-of-passing-values-between-windows-phone-7-pag/)

Hope you got solution